# Multi-line list view populated with arrays?

Tags: java, android

I have three arrays and I want to populate list view with them, till now I managed to populate list view with one array and array adapter, but now I need to put all three arrays in every item of list view.
Simple code would help lots.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Join the three array into a single one and Populate it as before

Comment: But every array have to be separated, like in three rows.

Comment: I need to create something to bind three arrays together.
For example: one array is for names, second for address and third for phone number, names are on the top, in the middle are address and in the bottom phone numbers.

Comment: Ok so you have to create custom adapter by Extending BaseAdapter class I am Posting a sample code refer to that

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code to create Custom Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private ArrayList<TimeRecord> record = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();

TextView txtTime, txtNote;


public ListViewAdapter() {

    record.add(new TimeRecord("38:23", "Feeling good!"));
    record.add(new TimeRecord("49:01", "Tired. Needed more caffeine"));
    record.add(new TimeRecord("26:21", "I’m rocking it!"));
    record.add(new TimeRecord("29:42",
            "Lost some time on the hills, but pretty good."));

}


@Override
public int getCount() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return record.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getItem(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_xml, parent, false);
    }
    TimeRecord time = record.get(position);

    txtTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    txtTime.setText(time.getTime());

    txtNote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
    txtNote.setText(time.getNote());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: What is (time.getTime()); or (time.getNote()); ??
Where are those methods?

Comment: these are the my class function